# import matlab (.mat) data in python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matlab, struct, double

I have a .mat data file which is a 1x1 struct with 15 fields. The field I'm interested in is a 400x2 double. I need to import this field into a python DataFrame. How can I do this? [left: data structure, right: the field that I want to import in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XR4K.png)

Comment: Check the [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've an idea, it's maybe not the good way to do it but there is a function in Matlab that allow you to save your array into a csv and you can read csv easily in python. :)

A bit barbarian but it may works.